# Can I use this screen with the Raspberry Pi Model 3 B

Tags: pi-3, screen, pitft

I found [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-7-inch-TFT-LCD-Display-Module-VGA-AV-FOR-Raspberry-Pi-Car-GPS-MP5-/252386234380?hash=item3ac364500c:g:GqUAAOSw8vZXMzz5) screen on eBay. It says it (comes without the Driver Board(explain?)). Could anyone tell me if I can use this screen with a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, if so how? It also says, "Can be equipped with a variety of standard and custom touch touch, resistive, capacitive", how do I achieve that? Or do you know of a better touchscreen 5-7 inch for cheaper or same price?

Thanks!

Comment: Shopping advice is off topic.  No, you can't use that screen with the Raspberry Pi.  You need the driver board as well, which probably costs twice as much if you can find one.

Comment: @joan: Since the first question is about the compatibility of a specific model item, I would say it's acceptable.  The rest of the question... not so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Driver_circuit) is what a driver board is. You would have to get one to use this screen. Personally, this ebay listing looks suspicious for all kinds of reasons and I would pass.

Answer (score 0):

What the OS running on Pi 3?

1. Windows 10 IoT.

   - Look at [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/supportedinterfaces#Miscellaneous) for compatible hardware. I see Chalkboard Electronics 7” LCD Capacitive Touchscreen Display.
2. Raspbian Jessie.

   - Look at [here](https://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-78156/l/raspberry-pi-7-touchscreen-display) for Official Touchscren Display.